# conflicting options: "network_mode: container" and "ports" mappings

Tags: docker

Background: I'd like to have one container that sets up a VPN and have multiple services using it.

In order to keep things related to each  VPN-using service together, I'd like the VPN-using services to specify the `ports` that they want to publish each in their own `docker-compose.yaml` file. But it seems I have to specify these in `docker-compose.yaml` for the shared VPN container. Is there any way for me to have multiple services use the same VPN-providing container, without the `docker-compose.yaml` file for the VPN specifying/knowing anything about the services that use it?

### Details

Here is a working solution:

**gluetun/docker-compose.yaml** provides the VPN:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  gluetun:
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun
    container_name: gluetun
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=vyprvpn
      - OPENVPN_USER=fred@flintstone.com
      - OPENVPN_PASSWORD=yadayadayada
      - SERVER_REGIONS=Germany
      - HTTPPROXY=on
      - FIREWALL_VPN_INPUT_PORTS=51413
    ports:
      # http proxy port for VPN - fine to have that here
      - 8123:8888

      # transmission ports
      # I'd like to move these to transmission/docker-compose.yaml
      - 9091:9091
      - 51413:51413
      - 51413:51413/udp
```

**transmission/docker-compose.yaml** is just an example of one out of N services that uses the VPN:

```yaml
services:
  transmission:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/transmission:latest
    container_name: transmission
    network_mode: container:gluetun
    environment:
      - PUID=1248
      - PGID=1248
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
    volumes:
      - /tmp/transmission/data:/config
      - /tmp/transmission/downloads:/downloads
      - /tmp/transmission/watch/folder:/watch
    # Specifying these causes the "conflicting options" error shown below
    # ports:
    #   - 9091:9091
    #   - 51413:51413
    #   - 51413:51413/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
```

See how `gluetun` container knows about the ports that `transmission` wants to publish/expose? (This is the only pattern I've seen in my searches, e.g. [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/u70ixo/where_can_i_find_help_with_gluetun_and_qbittorrent/), [2](https://drfrankenstein.co.uk/qbittorrent-with-gluetun-vpn-in-docker-on-a-synology-nas/) and [3](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/gluetun-docker-guide/))

If I try to set up `ports` in the VPN-using containers instead of in the `gluetun` VPN-providing container, I get:

`ERROR: for transmission  Cannot create container for service transmission: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode`

Are there any ways for me to have a single VPN-providing container that the others use, *while specifying the ports in the users' `docker-compose.yaml` files?*.